# How can I avoid DTOs duplication without inheritance?

Tags: java, inheritance, dto, code-duplication

I am connecting with many social networks for login in my application.
I have one DTO for each social network response.

```
public class GoogleUserInfo {
    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private AgeRange ageRange;
    // more specific fields
}

public class FacebookUserInfo {
    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String picture;
    // more specific fields
}

public class AppleUserInfo {
    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private Boolean emailVerified;
    // more specific fields
}
```

In each social network connector, I make similar steps to fetch the information, so I thought I could go with some DTO as follows:

```
public class SocialNetworkInfo {
    protected String id;
    protected String firstName;
    protected String lastName;
    protected String email;
}
```

Social networks DTOs could extend this to obtain the common fields. Then I could use this generic DTO to implement an abstract connector that deals with all the duplicate logic between connectors (make request, parse response, etc...):

```
abstract class AbstractConnector {
    abstract SocialNetworkInfo fetchUserInfo(String networkId);
    ...
}
```

But I realized that above, in my service layer, I would need those specific fields to make some changes and operations.

```
SocialNetworkInfo networkUserInfo = facebookConnector.fetchUserInfo(facebookId);
facebookService.updatePicture(networkUserInfo.getPicture()); // can't access this specific field
```

What do you think that's the best way to go through this situation without casting and avoiding logic or DTO duplication?

Would love to hear your thoughts.

Thanks!

Comment: `AbstractConnector<I extends SocialNetworkInfo>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use **inheritance**, I'd suggest to consider **composition**. The code can look as follows:

```
public class SocialNetworkInfo {
    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
}

public class GoogleUserInfo {
    private SocialNetworkInfo socialNetworkInfo;
    private AgeRange ageRange;
    // more specific fields
}

public class FacebookUserInfo {
    private SocialNetworkInfo socialNetworkInfo;
    private String picture;
    // more specific fields
}

public class AppleUserInfo {
    private SocialNetworkInfo socialNetworkInfo;
    private Boolean emailVerified;
    // more specific fields
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. I think I can't map JSON responses directly with this approach. If in fact there is a way either, please let me know!

Comment: @LeandroSuarez: Of course you **easily can** to map it to JSON. If you use JAX-RS or Spring Boot, you don't need even any configuration for this. And it is *very* strange that you asked for a solution "without inheritance" and accepted an answer that uses inheritance and *contradicts* to your requirement.

Comment: So true, sorry. I didn't realize I put **that condition** in the title. I was heading more for casting avoidance. I'm going to give you the credit in spite of I didn't implement your solution because the other fitted better in my code.

Comment: @LeandroSuarez: Relax :) If another answer is the best for you, you should accept it as the best. To avoid misunderstanding, you can adjust your question correspondingly and better explain *why* you talked about inheritance and *what* was the actual reason. Then your question may be helpful not only to you, but also to somebody else.

Answer (score 3):

According to your situation, all social network models have the same nature, so it's ok if you move common attributes to shared class like `CommonSocialInfo`. Then I would recommend to provide interface for the connectors like:

```
interface SocialNetworkConnector<T extends SocialNetworkInfo> {
    T fetchUserInfo(String userId);
}
```

Of course for common functionality(for connectors) is great idea to define common abstract class that implements interface above (implement Template pattern). I see that you are using `FacebookService` and related connector separately. I think that good idea to use composition in this case and make SocialNetworkService dependent on it connector. In short, FacebookService depends on FacebookConnecter and so on. Just a quick example:

```
public class FacebookService implements SocialNetworkService {
    private final SocialNetworkConnector<FacebookSocialInfo> connector;
    ...
}
```

And if you need to implement multiple social service, you can use Factory pattern to produce required service, quick example:

```
interface SocialNetworkServiceFactory {
    SocialNetworkService getFacebookService();
    ...
}
```

If you need more detailed help or you have troubles with understanding of the idea - feel free to ask!

Comment: Op said without inheritance, not sure why. I'd definitely do something like this...

Comment: I suppose this more just polymorphism than inheritance... Though

Comment: Thank you very much for this approach! It clarifies me how to tackle this down and make me get more interested in generics (which is pretty much unknown to me right now).
@RobC: sorry 
if i expressed myself wrong, I thought inheritance was limited for accessing subclass properties above in service layer, I was looking for alternatives or best way to implement this.

Comment: Great that it helps you!